# $\lim_{n\to 0} n^p\mu(\{x\in X:|f(x)|>n\})=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $f\in L^p(X)$, how to show $\lim_{n\to 0} n^p\mu(\{x\in X:|f(x)|>n\})=0$?

My attempt: Let $E$ be $\{x\in X:|f(x)>n|\}$, then by $\int_En^p<\int_E|f|^p<\int_X|f|^p<\infty$, we have $\mu(E)\cdot n^p<\infty$. But I can't show it's going to $0$.

Comment: Do we have assumptions on $X$? Is it of finite measure, or sigma-finite by any chance? Also, are you meant to have $n \to 0$?

Comment: @B.Mehta just a measure space

Comment: What does $\{x\in X:|f(x)>n|\}$ mean?

Comment: We have
$$n^p \mu(\{x : |f(x)| > n\}) \leq \int_{\{|f|>n\}} |f|^p d\mu = \int_X |f|^p \chi_{\{|f|>n\}} d\mu.$$
Since $f\in L^p(X)$ then $\mu(\{|f| = \infty\}) = 0$, hence $|f|^p \chi_{\{|f|>n\}} \to 0$ $\mu-$a.e. Morover, $|f|^p \chi_{\{|f|>n\}} \leq |f|^p \in L^1(X)$. Using dominated convergence theorem implies 
$$ \int_X |f|^p \chi_{\{|f|>n\}} d\mu \to 0.$$

Comment: @zhw sorry about that, it is fixed

Comment: And what values of $p$ are under investigation?

Comment: @zhw. there is no information about it

Comment: @nguyen0610 Note the limit is $n \to 0$, so your a.e. limit isn't justified. Although I personally suspect that's a typo

Comment: @B.Mehta: For $\mu-$a.e $x\in X$ we have $|f(x)| < \infty$. For such $x$ we have $|f(x)|^p \chi_{\{|f|> n\}}(x) =0$ if $n > |f(x)|$ hence $|f(x)|^p \chi_{\{|f|> n\}}(x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @nguyen0610 your claim is for $n\to\infty$, not for $n\to0$

Comment: Right, but the question concerns $n \to 0$ not $n \to \infty$. @nguyen0610

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see $n \to 0$.

Comment: @nguyen0610 but still a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\alpha >0$, define $f_\alpha(x) = f(x) \chi_{\{|f| \leq \alpha\}}(x)$, we have $f_\alpha(x) \to 0$ for all $x\in X$. Moreover, $|f_\alpha|^p \leq |f|^p$ then by dominated convergence theorem, we have
$$\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \int_X |f_\alpha|^p d\mu = 0.$$
For any $\epsilon >0$, we can choose $\alpha_0$ such that
$$\int_X |f_\alpha|^p d\mu \leq \epsilon,\qquad \forall\, \alpha \leq \alpha_0.$$
For $n < \alpha_0$, we have $\mu(\{|f|> n\}) = \mu(\{|f| > \alpha_0\}) + \mu(\{n < |f|\leq \alpha_0\})$, hence
$$n^p\mu(\{|f|> n\}) = n^p \mu(\{|f| > \alpha_0\}) + n^p\mu(\{n < |f|\leq \alpha_0\})\leq \int_X |f_{\alpha_0}|^p d\mu +n^p\mu(\{|f|> \alpha_0\}) \leq \epsilon + n^p\mu(\{|f|> \alpha_0\}).$$
Therefore
$$\limsup_{n\to 0}n^p\mu(\{|f|> n\}) \leq \epsilon,$$
for any $\epsilon >0$. This finishes the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take $p=1$ just to simplify things.

It's easy to see the result is true if $f$ is a simple function in $L^1.$ For the general $f\in L^1,$ let $\epsilon>0.$ Then there is a simple function $s\in L^1$ such that $\int_X |f-s| <\epsilon.$ Note that $\{|f|>t\}\subset \{|s|>t/2\} \cup \{|f-s|>t/2\}.$ We thus have

$$\tag 1 t\mu(\{|f|>t\}) \le t\mu(\{|s|>t/2\}) + t\mu(\{|f-s|>t/2\}).$$

But notice the last term is no more than $2\int_X|f-s| < 2\epsilon$ for any $t>0.$ Thus as $t\to 0^+,$ the $\limsup$ of the left side of $(1)$ is no more than $0+2\epsilon.$ Because $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small, we have shown the desired limit is $0.$

Comment: Could you please explain why $\{|f|>t\}\subset \{|s|>t/2\} \cup \{|f-s|>t/2\}.$? Thank you

Comment: @John11  Let $x$ be in the left hand set. If $x$ were not in one of the right hand sets, we would have $|f(x)| \le |s(x)| +|f(x)-s(x)| \le t/2 + t/2 =t,$ contradiction.